# What happen to temporary Java variables?

Tags: java, jvm

What is happening to variable when it is not longer needed.
For example

```
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     test();
 }
 public static void test(){
  String testVariable = "test";
  System.out.println(testVariable);   
 } 
}
```

---

What is happening to testVariable. Is it being removed from memory, or what. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To the variable or to the object it is referencing?

Comment: Can you answer both?

Comment: Please read about garbage collection: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Comment: Note that in this case the referenced object is a `String` object in the constant pool. It will not be reclaimed by GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable itself (`testVariable`), which only *points* to an object, and isn't an object in and of itself, is destroyed immediately when the `test` method exits, because it is allocated on the stack.

The `String` object pointed to by `testVariable` gets [garbage collected](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) at some point after Java can prove that there are no more references pointing to it.

Comment: Thanks for help, "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes".